# P6 reporting Activities Listing from Oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, reporting, bi-publisher, primavera

I am new to P6 reporting and I am facing an issue with writing a query to fetch all the activities under the wbs. Consider the following wbs hierachy

WBS LEVEL1

- WBS LEVEL 2A

  ACTIVITY1
  ACTIVITY2
- WBSLEVEL 2B

  ACTIVITY3
  ACTIVITY4

WBS LEVEL2 
..........................................

and so on.. A WBS can have any number of child wbs. In my reporting if i pass wbslevel 1 as a parameter value then all the activities under the wbs should be listed. Kindly help in achieving this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you can run the filter in the report for the specific WBS you are looking for activities it should work.

Regards,

Answer (score -1):

Are you writing a query on database?
If you are using Oracle than you can use connect by prior or Common Table Expression
If you are using the MS-SQL than CTE.

It should return all the activities from the WBS